# Make list of number from paired number in C#

Tags: c#, list, contains

I have a list of sublists with paired indexed number and its binary value. For example:

```
Variable        Value       
route.x[0,0]      0
route.x[0,1]      1
route.x[0,2]      0
route.x[0,3]      0
route.x[1,0]      0
route.x[1,1]      0
route.x[1,2]      0
route.x[1,3]      1
route.x[2,0]      0
route.x[2,1]      0
route.x[2,2]      0
route.x[2,3]      0
route.x[3,0]      0
route.x[3,1]      0
route.x[3,2]      1
route.x[3,3]      0
```

If the value of `route.x[i,j]` is `1`, then make a new list which contains that number in sequence. For that example, the new list will be: `route = 0 1 3 2`

So far, i have made this code:

```
//find optimal route
var route = new List<List<int>>();
for (int j = 0; j < C+1; ++j)
{
    if (routeopt.x[0, j] != 1)
    continue;
    List<int> subroute = new List<int>();
    subroute.Add(0);
    subroute.Add(j);
    route.Add(subroute);
}
```

This code's result is `route = 0 1`. After that I use this code to add new number (`3` and `2`).

```
for (int i = 1; i < C+1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < C+1; j++)
    {
        if (routeopt.x[i, j] == 1)
        {
            List<int> targetlist = route.Single(r => r.Contains(i));
            targetlist.Add(j);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is worked if only I have a route.x[i,j] with value 1 in ordered number. But if it is not ordered, for example (I only show variable with value 1):

```
Variable        Value       
route.x[0,4]      1
route.x[0,3]      1
route.x[4,1]      1
route.x[1,2]      1
```

It should be `route = 0 3` and `route = 0 4 1 2`. But it showed `Sequence contains no matching element` because index `1` is not contained in `route = 0 3` or `route = 0 4`. How to handled that problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found it by myself. After I got the first part, I use this code to add new number. Here is my code:

```
foreach (var subroute in route)
{
    int r = 0;
    while (r != subroute[subroute.Count - 1])
    {
        r = subroute[subroute.Count-1];
        for (int j = 1; j < C + 1; j++)
        {
            if (routeopt.x[r, j] == 1)
                subroute.Add(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It returns list of all routes. The List of int has route in inverse order so while displaying/using you should take care of it.

```
const int C = 4;
static int[,] route_x = new int[5, 5];

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var allRoutes = FindRoutes();
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}

private static List<List<int>> FindRoutes()
{
    route_x[0, 0] = 0;
    route_x[0, 1] = 1;
    route_x[0, 2] = 0;
    route_x[0, 3] = 0;
    route_x[1, 0] = 0;
    route_x[1, 1] = 0;
    route_x[1, 2] = 0;
    route_x[1, 3] = 1;
    route_x[2, 0] = 0;
    route_x[2, 1] = 0;
    route_x[2, 2] = 0;
    route_x[2, 3] = 0;
    route_x[3, 0] = 0;
    route_x[3, 1] = 0;
    route_x[3, 2] = 1;
    route_x[3, 3] = 0;
    route_x[0, 4] = 1;
    route_x[0, 3] = 1;
    route_x[4, 1] = 1;
    route_x[1, 2] = 1;

    var routes = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < C + 1; i++)
    {
        if (route_x[0, i] == 1)
        {
            var subroutes = FindNextRoute(i);
            foreach (var item in subroutes)
            {
                item.Add(0);
                routes.Add(item);
            }
        }                    
    }

    return routes;
}

private static List<List<int>> FindNextRoute(int i)
{
    var subroute = new List<List<int>>();
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < C + 1; j++)
    {
        if (route_x[i, j] == 1)
        {
            found = true;
            var tempRoutes = FindNextRoute(j);
            foreach(var item in tempRoutes)
            {
                item.Add(i);
                subroute.Add(item);
            }
        }                    
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        var singleitem = new List<int>();
        singleitem.Add(i);
        subroute.Add(singleitem);
    }

    return subroute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Single` method expects there is exactly 1 return value. if not it will throw an exception.

Try `SingleOrDefault`. This will return `null` if there is no element found.

```
List<int> targetlist = route.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Contains(i));
if(targetList != null)
    targetlist.Add(j);
```

Edit:

This will still crash if there are 2 lists that contain `i`.
To avoid this you could use `FirstOrDefault`